# How to fix mirroring of canvas in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mirroring

I have a simple question: How can I avoid flipping my healthbar attached to the main character? I have no idea what to do. Project you can download here: https://mega.nz/file/zUY0HYbL#ahwM_uGlp7-5iMLFjR1uaj6hgeVpjyhB3SCLe9xAt88

Sorry, I was not able to attach it here.

Comment: Answer is ready

Answer (score 0):

A long as you have a single value for the health bar like a float that determines  the scale of the healthbar you can simply add this line in the `void Update()` function and it will fix the healthbar from flipping:

```
health = Mathf.Clamp(health, 0, maxHealth);
```

Where **health** is the value that determines the length of the health bar and the scale of the health bar. (Sorry if it's confusing i just sont know what varibles you are using, you should include a piece of code next time i recomend) and where **maxHealth** is the maximum player health or the max scale of the healthbar.

[EDIT]
Put this line of code in you Update function.

```
currentHealth = Mathf.Clamp(currentHealth, 0, maxHealth);
```

So simply said, it fixes the **currentHealth** value between the range of 0 and **maxHealth**
So it can't go higher than **maxHealth** and lower than zero.

Good luck with your project. :D

Comment: BTW, the whole canvas flips, so thank you for your answer, but it did not help.

Comment: Oh. I think you are applying this flipping code for your character to your canvas or everything in your canvas. Check if you havent accidentally set the wrong game object as a variable in your code. You may have added the ui where it shows your player health. Its not flipping the whole cancas because the joystick is still in the same position though

Answer (score 0):

Here you are!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    public int maxHealth = 100;
    public int currentHealth;

    public Healthbar healthBar;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        healthBar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            TakeDamage(20);
        }
    }

    void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        currentHealth -= damage;

        healthBar.SetHealth(currentHealth);
    }
}
```